# Finite sum $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \frac{1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k r}{p}\right)}{1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k s}{p}\right)}$ for $\gcd(p,rs)=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, trigonometry, summation

I am wondering if there is a closed form to the following finite sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \frac{1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k r}{p}\right)}{1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k s}{p}\right)},$$

where $\gcd(p,rs)=1$ and $r,s,p$ are positive integers, and if so how would I go about figuring out the closed form?

EDIT: I arrived at this sum as I am investigating the value of the $T_2$-norm of units in the cyclotomic ring $\mathbb{Z}(\zeta_{p})$ for prime $p$. The $T_2$-norm of an element $x \in K$ for some number field $K$ of degree $n$ is defined:

$$
||x|| = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |\sigma_i(x)|^2\right)^{1/2},
$$

where $\{\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_n\}$ are the embeddings of $K$ and $|x|^2 = x\bar{x}$ where the bar represents complex conjugation.

Lemma: For $\gcd{(rs,p)}=1$, $\frac{\zeta^r -1}{\zeta^s -1}$ is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}(\zeta_p)$.

Proof: Let $r \equiv st \mod p$. Then $\frac{\zeta^r-1}{\zeta^s-1} = 1 + \zeta^s + \dots + \zeta^{s(t-1)} \in \mathbb{Z}(\zeta_p)$, and its inverse is also in $\mathbb{Z}(\zeta_p)$ by the same logic.

So for unit $u$ of the aforementioned form, we have:

$$
|u|^2 = \frac{\zeta^r-1}{\zeta^s-1} \frac{\zeta^{-r}-1}{\zeta^{-s}-1} = \frac{2-(\zeta^r + \zeta^{-r})}{2-(\zeta^{s} + \zeta^{-s})} = \frac{1-\cos(\frac{2\pi r}{p})}{1-\cos(\frac{2\pi s}{p})}.
$$

Since $\sigma_k(\zeta_p) = \zeta_p^k$, we have:

$$
||u||^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \frac{1-\cos(\frac{2\pi k r}{p})}{1-\cos(\frac{2\pi k s}{p})}.
$$

Comment: Already the fact that the result is integer is interesting. (+1) How did you find the expression?

Comment: What do you know about [Ramanujan sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_sum)?

Comment: By the way, write **\gcd** to generate $\gcd$ as opposed to $gcd$ :)

Comment: Hi @user, thanks for the upvote! I'm investigating the absolute value of units over cyclotomic fields of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^a})$ and then summing these absolute values (squared) over all the embeddings, which results in the sum above.

Comment: It could be useful if you sketch _in the question_ how you arrived at the sum.

Comment: @user I have edited my post to give context of the sum.

Comment: How did you get the factor 2 in the expression for $|u|^2$?

Comment: @user That was actually a mistake, which I just realised that I have made and will now correct. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe to find a closed form for the sum:

$$\forall r,s,p:\quad\gcd(r s, p)=1:\quad   
\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \frac{1-\cos\frac{2\pi k r}{p}}{1-\cos\frac{2\pi k s}{p}}=q(p-q),\tag{1}$$ 
with
$$
q=r s^{\phi(p)-1}\text{ mod }p\tag{2},
$$
where $\phi(p)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

The proof of the expression (1) outlined by [Jack D'Aurizio](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/44121/jack-daurizio) can be completed in the following way:

Observing that (1) is a linear combination of [Fejér kernels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel), $F_q(x)$, rewrite it as:
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{\sin\frac{\pi k q}{p}}{\sin\frac{\pi k}{p}}  \right)^2 =\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} qF_q\left(\frac{2\pi k}{p}\right)
=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\sum_{|l|\leq q}\left(q-|l|\right)e^{\frac{lk}{p}2\pi i}
=\sum_{|l|\leq q}\left(q-|l|\right)\Phi(l,p),
$$
with
$$
\Phi(l,p)=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}e^{\frac{lk}{p}2\pi i}=
p\delta_{l0}-1.\tag{3} $$
The proof of (3) for $l\ne 0$ follows from the observation that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}e^{\frac{lk}{p}2\pi i}=0,
$$
as the sum runs over all roots of the polynomial $z^\frac{p}{\gcd(l,p)}-1$ (each of the roots entering the sum $\gcd(l,p)$ times).

Thus
$$
\sum_{|l|\leq q}\left(q-|l|\right)\Phi(l,p)=q(p-1)-2\sum_{l=1}^{q-1}l
=q(p-1)-q(q-1)=q(p-q),
$$
as claimed.

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, but we have:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \frac{1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k r}{p}\right)}{1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k s}{p}\right)} = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi k r}{p}\right) \prod_{j \neq k} \sin^2\left(\frac{2 \pi j s}{p}\right)}{\prod_{j=1}^{p-1} \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi j s}{p}\right)} =\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi k r}{p}\right) \prod_{j \neq k} \sin^2\left(\frac{2 \pi j s}{p}\right)}{p^2},
$$

so it would suffice to show the top of the fraction is equal to $p^2 q(p-q)$.

Comment: $2\pi$ in the product on the numerator is meant to be $\pi$.

Comment: @Chris I have added the proof of the expression.

Comment: Perfect - marked as correct answer. Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 1):

First, we can focus on the case where $(r,s) \leq p-1$, as for other cases we just consider the operation $\mod p$.

With a simple trigonometric manipulation, the sum above becomes

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi k r}{p})}{\sin(\frac{\pi k s}{p})}  \right)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}  \left(\frac{ e^{\frac{i\pi k r}{p}} - e^{- \frac{i\pi k r}{p}}}{ e^{\frac{i\pi k s}{p}} - e^{- \frac{i\pi k s}{p}}}  \right)^2 = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}  \left(\frac{ e^{\frac{i\pi k r}{p}} - e^{- \frac{i\pi k r}{p}}}{ e^{\frac{i\pi k s}{p}} - e^{- \frac{i\pi k s}{p}}}  \right)^2.
\end{equation}

I guess at this point it is possible to apply Ramanujan sums as suggested above, but I am not sure how.

It is interesting to notice that this sum (by simulations) is always an integer number.

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis ensure that both $r$ and $s$ are invertible in $\mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})^*$, hence
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi k r}{p})}{\sin(\frac{\pi k s}{p})}  \right)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi k a}{p})}{\sin(\frac{\pi k}{p})}  \right)^2$$
where $a= rs^{-1}\pmod{p}$, by reindexing. By the [Fejér kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel)
$$ \left(\frac{\sin\frac{nx}{2}}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}\right)^2=\sum_{|j|\leq n}\left(n-|j|\right) e^{ijx} $$
hence by setting $x=\frac{2\pi k}{p}$, $n=a$ and summing over $k\in[1,p-1]$

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi k a}{p})}{\sin(\frac{\pi k}{p})}  \right)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\sum_{|j|\leq a}\left(a-|j|\right) \exp\left(\frac{2\pi ijk}{p}\right) $$
The fact that such sums leads to integers now is straightforward by exchanging $\sum_{k}$ and $\sum_{|j|}$: for any fixed value of $j$, the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ijk}{p}\right)$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: is there an explicit form for the integer value though? I arrived at this result too by the unit expansion I showed when showing the context for my question.

Comment: @Chris: well, the explicit form can be derived from computing $\sum_{k}\exp(2\pi i j k/p)$ and exploiting Ramanujan sums.

Comment: Thanks for all your help - much appreciated